# Varchar to nvarchar in ssis

Tags: ssis

In my ssis package, I using script task which dynamically creates a data flow task and executes it.My source is oracle and destination sql server table. Now the problem is some columns from data source have **varchar** datatypes, but in my destination table, i want to use nvarchar datatype since that is what my client needs. But then obviously i get the unicode to non unicode error and data flow fails. So is there a way to achieve this without using any transformation since data flow is dynamically created. 
At source I have a column of varchar datatypes but in destination I want to dump that data to nvarchar datatype column. Can XML mapping files be of help in this or what.

Please help

Regards

Comment: If you're dynamically creating your data flows, why can't you dynamically inject a derived column/data conversion component into the pipeline.

Comment: As a general bit of SO guidance, questions about code that don't provide code are exceptionally challenging to debug